# Strange issue with using Java reflection across multiple projects

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have created a Java project that implements a State Machine. The idea behind it is that the SM itself runs in a background thread as a simple loop over an array of objects representing different actions.

The actions in question are from another object called an ActionPack that contains the Action objects.

This works well using Java reflection to look into the instantiated ActionPack at run time and import them into the state machine where they are pushed onto the array. The state machine then iterates over the array when told to run and calls the execute method of each action.

As I said, this works well and all unit tests are green ... but only when I run the them from within IntelliJ. If I try running them via "mvn test", the Reflection code fails to find the classes within the action pack.

This is the failing reflection method:

```
  /**
   * Use introspection to read in all of the classes in a given action pack
   * Filter out the ones that are actions and return them in an array
   */
  public ArrayList getActionsFromActionPack(
    DataAccessLayer dataAccessLayer,
    String runRoot
  ) {

    String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();

    System.out.println("PACKAGE NAME = " + packageName);

    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */), new ResourcesScanner())
      .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
      .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(packageName))));

    Set<Class<? extends Action>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Action.class);

    System.out.println("Number of classes = " + classes.size());

    ArrayList<IAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Class a : classes) {
      try {
        Action action = (Action) Class.forName(a.getName()).newInstance();
        // Give the action access to the DAL and path to control directory
        action.setDataAccessLayer(dataAccessLayer);
        action.setRunRoot(runRoot);
        actions.add(action);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
    return actions;
  }
```

With those debug print statements in there, when I run the Unit Tests from within IntelliJ I see this output:

```
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack
    Number of classes = 7
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack
    Number of classes = 7
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack
    Number of classes = 7
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.test.classes
    Number of classes = 1
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack
    Number of classes = 7
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack
    Number of classes = 7

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I run via mvn test:

```
    PACKAGE NAME = com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack
    Number of classes = 0
    Exception in thread "UnitTestThread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.InfiniteStateMachine.run(InfiniteStateMachine.java:36)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So it looks like the reflective method correctly identifies the package that we're in, but then fails to find the classes within it if called via maven.

The failure occurs in the final line of setup() of the unit test when I call importActionPack

```
      @Before
      public void setup() {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL is = loader.getResource(PROPERTIES);
        ismCoreActionPack = new ISMCoreActionPack();
        infiniteStateMachine = new InfiniteStateMachine(is.getPath());
        infiniteStateMachine.importActionPack(ismCoreActionPack);
      }
```

This code is spread across three projects:

```
infinite-state-machine (The state machine itself)
infinite-state-machine-common (Where the action pack and action types are defined)
infinite-state-machine-core (The action pack I'm failing to import)
```

The Action Pack has an interface in infinite-state-machine-common:

```
    package com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.common.action;

    import com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.common.dal.DataAccessLayer;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public interface IActionPack {
      JSONObject getJsonObjectFromResourceFile(String fileName);
      ArrayList getActionsFromActionPack(
        DataAccessLayer dataAccessLayer,
        String runRoot
      );
    }
```

The actual implementation of the action pack is also in infinite-state-machine-common:

```
    public class ActionPack implements IActionPack
```

And that is where the reflections method public ArrayList getActionsFromActionPack() is found.

The Action class and its interface are also in infinite-state-machine-common:

```
    package com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.common.action;

    import com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.common.dal.DataAccessLayer;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public interface IAction {
      void execute();

      Boolean active();
      boolean active(String action);
      void activate(String actionName);
      Boolean afterActionsComplete();
      Boolean beforeActionsComplete();
      void clearPayload(String actionName);
      String createRunDirectory(String directory);
      void deactivate();
      void deactivate(String actionFlag);
      JSONObject getJsonObjectFromFile(String fileName);
      ArrayList<JSONObject> getUnprocessedMessages();
      void insertMessage(JSONObject message);
      void insertProperty(String property, String value);
      void markMessageProcessed(Integer id);
      void setDataAccessLayer(DataAccessLayer dataAccessLayer);
      void setRunRoot(String runRoot);
      String queryProperty(String property);
      String queryRunPhase();
      void setState(String stateName);
      void updatePayload(String actionName, String payload);
      void updateProperty(String property, String value);
      void updateRunPhase(String runPhase);
      void unsetState(String stateName);
    }
```

The Action parent class itself is too big to post here but is defined in the same package:

```
public abstract class Action implements IAction {

}
```

If it helps, this is a typical action from the core package showing the execute method:

```
    package com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.core.action_pack;

    import com.github.museadmin.infinite_state_machine.common.action.Action;

    /**
     * Action that verifies the state of the ISM and confirms
     * we have booted up correctly and can now run
     */
    public class ActionConfirmReadyToRun extends Action {

      /**
       * Confirm we've got through the bootstrapping process ok.
       * and all BEFORE actions completed
       */
      public void execute() {
        if (active()) {
          if (beforeActionsComplete()) {
            setState("READY_TO_RUN");
            updateRunPhase("RUNNING");
            deactivate();
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

SUMMARY

I don't know if this is a problem with the way I am using the Reflections library as I would expect it to fail when I ran the tests from IntelliJ...

So perhaps this is an issue with Maven?

I have built and locally installed all of the projects, so they are definitely available and built at this point.

FYI - At the moment I have put the Unit tests in their own separate project to prevent this issue from breaking the build as I push the projects to Nexus.

Any help or guidance on debugging this issue would be much appreciated.

Brad

Comment: If it fails based on missing classes your dependencies are not correct...Furthermore if those tests you have put into a separate project are really unit test than it's wrong cause the belong to the classes/module they are testing in ...should be src/test/java...Apart from that the exception `    Exception in thread "UnitTestThread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` shows me there is something different wrong...What about state design pattern ?

Comment: The exception is because the array of action classes is empty. As I explain in the post, the tests are in a separate project because I can't get past this issue. If the maven dependencies were not correct then the unit tests would fail when run from IntelliJ. If I could run the tests from maven successfully, I would put them back in each project. But thanks  anyway.

Comment: IntelliJ/Eclipse have sometimes their own imagination of a classpath...better get it run with Maven..Do you have that project somewhere on Github ?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine-common https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine-core-action-pack https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine-parent-pom and finally the test harness https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine-test

Comment: Re "_If the maven dependencies were not correct then the unit tests would fail when run from IntelliJ._" That's not necessarily so. Eclipse, for instance, has a property for Maven projects to resolve dependencies from the workspace, rather than from any repository.

Comment: Ah, thank you, Gerold. I didn't know that. Could you provide a link to anything describing how that works?